# Kolkata to Guangzhou, China. Ticket Transit to Bangkok suvarnabhumi airport

Tags: visas, transit, bangladeshi-citizens, bkk

I am a Bangladeshi citizen.  will be traveling from Kolkata to Guangzhou, China.  Ticket Transit to Bangkok Bangkok suvarnabhumi airport transit ticket.  Do I need a Bangkok visa?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need visa, if you want to transit through BKK airport. Provided you have ticket in same itenary and it is within 12 hours.